# Is there a simple way to keep mappers and reducers run for a specific time?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

For some testing purposes I want a map reduce job that will run at max for 1 hour and at least 50 minutes. The actual processing is completely irrelevant.

I wonder if there is any APIs that would help me achieve this. I would ideally want to generate some fake data till the time limit is crossed.

P.S. : The question is for academic interest only. I am fully aware that Map Reduce is probably designed not for these sort of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the maximum time limit for a job using the configuration object

```
conf.set("mapreduce.task.timeout",3600000); // change the time limit to 1h
```

the job will be killed after the specified time is out.

Comment: I think that timeout is applicable only if no context.write happens in that timeframe and of course I want the lower limit too. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it is possible with `Hadoop` or not.

But usually in Linux you use `crontab` for scheduled tasks.

Just set two scheduled commands in crontab.

1. Start the Hadoop job
2. After 50 minutes stop the particular Hadoop job.